# How to filter an array based on a range and then take an additional sample either side of result

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am looking for a simple solution to the following example:

```
let rangeOfInterest = [25 , 44];
let input = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60];
```

I'm interested in all values that are greater than 25 and less than 44 (inclusive). The rangeOfInterest may be completely inside or completely outside the input values, other examples include [85, 95] or [0, 100].

```
output1 = [30, 40];
```

If a value exists either side of this output then take that sample as well;

```
finalOutput = [20, 30, 40, 50];
```

I can achieve the above by applying a filter to the array then finding the index of the first and last elements of the result and extracting the additional samples based on that (if they exist). Is there a cleaner way of achieving this that doesn't involve ~20 lines of code?

Note: samples will be floats, used ints for a simpler example.

Comment: What is the logic to get `finalOutput`?

Comment: You don't need 20 lines of code: using `Array.prototype.findIndex` find indexes of the first value larger 25, and the first value larger than 40. Then `Array.prototype.slice`. Looks more like 3 lines. `input.slice(input.findIndex(v => v > 25) - 1, input.findIndex(v => v > 40) + 1)` + a little bit of handling edge cases.

Comment: The logic is two parts, apply a filter for the upper range, if samples exist, check if an additional sample exists next in the array. Apply again for lower range sample.

Comment: Will `rangeOfInterest` always contain two values?

Comment: @HassanImam yes

Comment: @zerkms can you post your succinct example as an answer covering the edge cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the index of the first item that is larger than the minimum range, and the index of the first item that is larger than the maximum range, and slice according to the indexes (minIndex - 1, maxIndex + 1).

```js
const fn = ([min, max], arr) => {
  const startIndex = arr.findIndex(n => n > min); // find the index of the first item that is larger than min
  const endIndex = arr.findIndex(n => n > max); // find the index of the first item that is smaller than max
    
  return arr.slice(
    startIndex > 1 ? startIndex - 1 : 0,
    endIndex === -1 ? arr.length : endIndex + 1
  );
};


const input = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60];

console.log(fn([25 , 44], input));

console.log(fn([25 , 65], input));

console.log(fn([-25 , 65], input));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I may not have been clear about the variability of the rangeOfInterest (updated answer) but this doesn't work if rangeOfInterest is outside input array e.g. [25, 65]

Comment: Great answer thanks, final edge case is if range is totally outside input array e.g. [65, 75]. I can cover that by checking if startIndex and endIndex are -1 in an if statement, but is there a nicer way of covering this? I only ask as I'm trying to improve my coding ability and finding different approaches to solving problems.

Comment: In all above you should take the last, and in all below you should take the 1st. I think you'll need to check it at the start if(min > arr[arr.length - 1]) and (max < arr[0]), and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let input = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60];
let rangeOfInterest = [25 , 44];

let newOutput = input.filter(function(number) {
  return Math.min(...rangeOfInterest) <= number && Math.max(...rangeOfInterest) >= number;
});

newOutput.push( Math.floor(Math.min(...rangeOfInterest) / 10) * 10 ); //adding 20
newOutput.push( Math.floor(Math.max(...rangeOfInterest) / 10) * 10 ); // adding 40

console.log(newOutput)
```

Comment: This doesn't cover the edge cases of rangeOfInterest (updated my question) but upvoted because I really like Math.min(...rangeOfInterest) !

Answer (score 0):

```js
let roi = [25 , 44]; //simplifying range of interest variable name
    let arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60];
    function inRange(val1,val2){//assuming val1<val2 always
    return (num)=>{
         return num>=val1 && num<=val2;
       }
    }
    let firstInd=0;
    let lastInd=0;
    var resultArr = arr.filter((val,ind) => {
           let match = inRange(roi[0],roi[1])(val);
           if(!firstInd){
              firstInd=match?ind:0;
           }
           lastInd = match&&(ind>lastInd)?ind:lastInd;
           return match;
           });
    lastInd<arr.length?resultArr.push(arr[lastInd+1]):'';
    firstInd>0?resultArr.splice(0,0,arr[firstInd-1]):'';
    console.log(resultArr);
```